# Add Automatic Jump Break After 1st Image JavaScript in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a blog for Japanese Manga, all the posts I put always only contains of only pics and no text: 
http://rawmangaread.blogspot.in/

I found a blogger theme particularly perfect for this category.
The theme provider had mentioned in the instructions that I must add a jump break after every 1st image of the post or else some posts will not show up in the homepage. And I am going through the same crisis right now.

When I open the below URL:
http://rawmangaread.blogspot.in/search/label/?max-results=1000
Some posts are missing.
You can see that at the end of the page in the above like it starts from Chapter 5. But I checked several times and confirmed that chapter 1 to 4 has been published perfectly and showup in other places while not showing up only in the above link.

All I want is a javascript to solve the problem.
What I want to do is to add a jump break i.e.
`<!--more-->`
 to everypost **after the 1st image** automatically and **if possible** add the option to ignore adding jump break if a jump break already exists after 1st image.

Comment: Something like this isn't possible without utilizing the Blogger API. This will require the creation of a custom tool which fetches all the posts via the API, then parses them to insert the Jump Break (`<!--more-->`) when certain conditions are met (aka there is no Jump break already existing & inserting the Jump break after the first image). Once it has changed all the post, then update them all on the blog via the Blogger API.